# SVD at rank K for a weight matrix

Tags: rank, svd

'''import numpy

u,s,v = np.linalg.svd(weight, full_matrices=False)'''

where weight is matrix of 3 channels (rgb). I would like to find SVD at certain rank k. Can anyone help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i read [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), the rank k is not selective in Numpy library. Instead you can cut output matr1ices to keep top elements of matrix sigma.